# Cassandra parallel insert performance c#

Tags: c#, cassandra

When testing Cassandra C# insert performance on single node i7 8cores got only 100 inserts/sec. Are there any code improvements possible using Datastax Cassandra driver? Tried async and sync Session.Execute, but performance is very poor.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    //   CREATE TABLE table1(
    //   col1 text,
    //   col2 timestamp,
    //   col3 int,
    //   col4 text,
    //   PRIMARY KEY(col1, col2, col3)
    //   );

    PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
    poolingOptions
        .SetCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.Local, 1280)
        .SetMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.Local, 1280)
        .SetCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.Remote, 1280)
        .SetMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.Remote, 1280);

    poolingOptions
        .SetMaxSimultaneousRequestsPerConnectionTreshold(HostDistance.Local, 32768)
        .SetMinSimultaneousRequestsPerConnectionTreshold(HostDistance.Remote, 2000);

    var cluster = Cluster.Builder()
        .AddContactPoints("localhost")
        .WithPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
        .WithQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.One))
        .WithLoadBalancingPolicy(new RoundRobinPolicy())
        .Build();

    var options = new ParallelOptions();
    options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50;

    using (var session = cluster.Connect("keyspace1"))
    {
        var ps = session.Prepare("INSERT INTO table1(col1,col2,col3,col4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

        var r = Parallel.For(0, 1000, options, (x) =>
        {
            {
                var statement = ps.Bind("123456", DateTime.UtcNow, x, "1234 some log message goes here. Hello world. 123334556567586978089-==00");
                var t = session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
                t.Wait();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Also check Cassandra configurations to improve throughput

Comment: Tests were done after clean Cassandra install. Checked documentation and cassandra.yaml, but I don't find any reasonable parameters to configure (results are 1000 inserts per 10 seconds).

Comment: To start with, you can try increasing heap size, vary record size, increase number of Cassandra write connections etc and see if you get Imrovement. Cassandra scales and performs well with multinode cluster than single node.

Comment: Currently tested Cassandra instance allocates 4GB of memory (for 20-30K rows it is plenty). Record size is miserable and only 4 columns. Also I tried to use separate sessions for statements, but that was even slower. I expected (>5000 inserts per second, but got ~100)

Comment: Seems like something is not right in your case. Can you try to benchmark with YCSB and see if you get similar results? Try to monitor resource util on cassandra server. If possible your YCSB/C# code should run on different server than cassandra (assuming they are on same machine as of now)

Comment: ycsb results are quite similar: [OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 4747.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 210.6593638087213
[INSERT], Operations, 1000.0
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 2128.991
[INSERT], MinLatency(us), 1203.0
[INSERT], MaxLatency(us), 8903.0
[INSERT], 95thPercentileLatency(us), 2971.0
[INSERT], 99thPercentileLatency(us), 3065.0
[INSERT], Return=OK, 1000

Comment: Looks like you tried with only 1000 records with single thread. Try with more number of records 100K and with multiple threads.YCSB also supports throttling. While doing that monitor resources on Cassandra node to see if anything chokes.

Comment: ycsb 100K with 10 threads performance would be ok. [OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 12804.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 7810.059356451109
[INSERT], Operations, 100000.0
[INSERT], AverageLatency(us), 1018.59368
[INSERT], MinLatency(us), 113.0
[INSERT], MaxLatency(us), 46559.0
But then how to achieve such performance with c#? Tried parallel 100K - result: 300ops/s.

Comment: Now we can say its problem with your code. I am not an C# expert but IMO you should profile your code and see what is actually limiting your throughput.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of connections (> 1K) is way too large, with modern Cassandra instances (2.1+) a single connection would be enough.

The fastest way to do asynchronous operations would be to launch n operations and each time a task is completed launch a new one.

Using a `SemaphoreSlim` would do the trick to limit the amount of concurrent operations or you could manually do it using continuations.

If you don't want to write that code, you can use a small utility package I've created [ConcurrentUtils](https://github.com/jorgebay/concurrent-utils):

```
// Execute 1,000,000 times
// limiting the maximum amount of parallel async operations to 512
await ConcurrentUtils.Times(1000000, 512, _ => 
  session.ExecuteAsync(ps.Bind(parameters)));
```

Comment: Works fine. 6.6sec - 500000 inserts - 75757 Inserts/sec